# BBox missing when converting TIGER to GeoJSON

Tags: shapefile, geojson, ogr2ogr, census

I can't get the bounding boxes of polygons if TIGER/Line shape files when converting them to GeoJSON using FWTools. The other default information is present and there is no difference between the GeoJSON files created with or without -lco WRITE_BBOX=YES. Here is the command line I used:

ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON myF.json myF.shp -lco WRITE_BBOX=YES

Answer (score 1):

WRITE_BBOX parameters is supported for OGR >= 1.9.0.
FwTools contains previous version of OGR.
You should download the latest installer version (for now 1.10.0) from [here](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).